# How to change the colour of the line when I strike out a sentence

Tags: color, soul

I have the following MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\st{I want to strike out this sentence} using a red line and I want to replace it with this.

\end{document}
```

I would like to strike out the sentence using a red line instead of a black one in order to make the change easier to be noted. But I cannot figure out how. Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set the wished color with command `\setstcolor{red}`.

So with the following code

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{soul}
\setstcolor{red} % <====================================================
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\st{I want to strike out this sentence} using a red line and I want to 
replace it with this.

\end{document}
```

you get the result:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setstcolor{red}
\begin{document}

\st{I want to strike out this sentence} using a red line and I want to replace it with this.

\end{document}
```